# Session variables not passing to next file

Tags: php, session-variables

So I've searched this site about this issue and tried what has been suggested and still no luck.  I thought maybe it was my 'server' (On my tablet using KSWEB, no computer right now) so I created 2 simple files to share a session variable between the two and it worked fine.  I have no idea why this isn't working for these two.  I'm trying to create a login page (an insecure one, I know).  The error function USED to work (this is what gets me), and now it doesn't.  The files are below.  I only included the top portion of admin.php because I've commented out the rest.  It really shouldn't matter.  Right now, if you submit the form without entering anything into the admin prompt, an error should display next to the asterisk saying "Admin needs to be filled out".  Despite my best efforts, this doesn't work anymore and I'm completely stumped as to why.

Login.php

```
<?php 
session_start();
?>

<html>
<head>
  <style>
  .error {color: #FF0000;}
  </style>

  <script>
  function submitForm()
  {
  document.adminform.submit();
  }
  </script>
</head>

<?php echo $_SESSION["adminErr"];?>

<h2>Administrator login page</h2>
<form method="post" action="admin.php" name="adminform">
  Admin: <input type="text" name="admin" style="position:absolute; left:100px">
  <span class="error" style="position:absolute; left:285px">*<?php echo $_SESSION["adminErr"];?></span>
  <br><br>
  Password: <input type="password" name="password" style="position:absolute; left:100px">
  <span class="error" style="position:absolute; left:285px">*<?php echo $_SESSION["passwordErr"];?></span>
  <br><br>
  <button onclick="submitForm()">Submit</button>
</form>

<br><br><br>
<p><?php echo $_SESSION["flogin"];?></p>

</html>

<?php
session_destroy();
?>
```

Admin.php

```
<?php

session_start();

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == POST)
{
  if (empty($_POST["admin"])) // Check to make sure Admin field is filled out
    {
    $_SESSION["adminErr"] = "Admin field must filled"; // Set error if not filled
    header("location:login.php"); // Return to login page
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: One security aspect is to always (just get used to do it **always**) use `exit;` after `header('Location: login.php');`.

Comment: This actually solved the problem for me.  Everything is working again.  Mind explaining why this works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't destroy the session at the end of the file..

```
</html>

<?php
session_destroy();
?>
```

Also you should put `exit;` after each `header('Location: ...');`.

When sending the header, the browser recognized to change the location but the script does not end. The browser in fact, would not even have to follow the header, it can also just go on with the script. You have to stop the script because the headers do not exit the script.

Comment: Tried this, multiple times actually, still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
<button onclick="submitForm()">Submit</button>
```

use

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Then put a check before echoing

```
<?php echo isset($_SESSION["adminErr"])? $_SESSION["adminErr"]: "not set" ;?>
```

---

further debugging:

```
var_dump($_POST);
var_dump($_POST["admin"]);
var_dump($_SESSION);
var_dump($_SESSION["adminErr"]);
```